# How to wait for homepage in flutter until firestore check query?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Here i implement firebase login, register, home page setting in my flutter app.

For this i want to set Homepage according to firestore query in `main.dart`

Here is my code

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false,
      home: setHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

 setHomePage() {
  if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser==null){
    return Login();
  }
  else {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(AppString.FB_USERS).doc(
        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).get().then((
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        return UserStateJunction();
      }
      else {
        return User();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I think this code has no error ,
But this is not work and homepage is not waiting for firestore query , it throws null exception

```
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/", null) in the
_WidgetAppState. Make sure your root app widget has provided a way to generate this route. Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:

For the "/" route, the "builder" property, if non-null, is used.
Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "builder" and "routes".
Finally, if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called. Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
   runApp(  YourApp() )
}

class YourApp extends StatelessWidget{

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
            future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot){
                       if (snapshot.hasData){
                           FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data; // this is your user instance
                           /// is because there is user already logged
                           return MainScreen();
                        }
                         /// other way there is no user logged.
                         return LoginScreen();
             }
          );
    }
}
```